# Are there better theories of heat capacity than the Debye's model? If yes! what are they and how they are better?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics

I personally don't get a feel when I study Debye's model, maybe because I am not well-versed in continuum mechanics, even after studying both theories i.e. of Einstein and Debye, I still feel Einstein's theory(although a bit inaccurate) takes into account things more intuitively while Debye uses out of the box approach.

Comment: Can you explain why you feel Einstein's model feels more intuitively realistic to you? There are more realistic models than Debyes (typically with a anharmonic terms to more accurately model inter atomic forces) but they (to my knowledge) universally build on Debye's model rather than Einstein's

Comment: Debye's model is unequivocally more accurate than Einstein's at low temperatures, though Einstein's was very good for its time, and accurate considering its simplicity

Comment: You could decide to make fewer assumptions than Debye, e.g. don't take the linearisation, or use an even better physical model. But there is no situation whereby Einstein's model is more sensible. You need to explain what you want to see in an answer.